# Can Jmeter only measure OS level metrics?

Tags: mysql, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I use JMeter for performance testing of various application, but I generally measure OS level metrics, like CPU, memory, network usages.
Can I use application specific metrics through JMeter, for example, in MySQL, I searched that following are the metrics to be monitored for performance benchmarking:

- Connection Time
- Request Statistics
- Connection Statistics
- Thread Details
- Table Lock Statistics
- Key efficiency
- Query Hit Ratio
- Query Cache Hitrate
- Replication Details
- etc.

Can these be monitored through JMeter?

Comment: You can check out:  [Catci](http://www.cacti.net/), [Monit](http://mmonit.com/), [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)

Comment: Is that possible using Jmeter by using any custom Listeners?

Comment: If answer is ok for you you should accept it so that it help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at jmeter-plugins from Pg@gc:

- http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/

> The sql query should return a single row with a single column and that value should be a number.

It will graph lines.

Comment: What type of graph does DbMon listener produce?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PerfMon Pluging. Its basic monitoring, but easy to use!

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/